# Prove for all sets $A, B$, and $C$, if $A \subseteq (B-C)$ then $A \cap (C-B) = \varnothing$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know that it is true, and that it is possible to prove it with contradiction, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Comment: From the first, $x\in A$ implies $x\notin C$. Then any element of $A\cap (C-B)$ is both $\notin C$ and $\in C$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $A\cap(C-B)\neq\varnothing$. This means there exists $x\in A\cap(C-B)$, which means $x\in A$ and $x\in(C-B)$.

$x\in(C-B)$ implies $x\in C$ and $x\notin B$. Therefore, $x\notin (B-C)$.

Hence we have an element in $A$ which is not in $(B-C)$ so $A\not\subseteq(B-C)$.

The contrapositive of this is the statement you wish to prove.